# Javascript setter and getter return different outputs

Tags: javascript, getter

I've been using the keyword get and set of JavaScript but I don't think that I'm implementing it correctly.

```
_maxWinnings: -1,
get maxWinnings() { 
    return this._maxWinnings;
}, 
setMaxWinnings : function( value ) {
    this._maxWinnings = value;
    // This works fine.
    // this.maxWinnings = value;
}
```

I've done series of tests and the results are not as expected.

```
console.log( this.sgd._maxWinnings );
> -1
console.log( this.sgd.maxWinnings );
> -1
console.log( this.sgd.setMaxWinnings(10) );
> undefined
console.log( this.sgd._maxWinnings );
> 10
console.log( this.sgd.maxWinnings );
> -1
```

I hope that you could help me out.

Comment: I couldn't replicate your problem: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taz7e/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> setMaxWinnings : function( value ) {
>     // This works fine:
>     // this.maxWinnings = value;
> }
> ```

No, it doesn't. You've written a setter method that you need to call (like `sgd.setMaxWinnings(10))`, but if you want a property assignment setter then you will need to use

```
set maxWinnings( value ) {
    this._maxWinnings = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The get and set keywords don't work that way.

```
function SGD()
{
    this._maxWinnings = 0;
    return this;
}
Object.defineProperty(SGD, 'maxWinnings', {
    get : function () { return this._maxWinnings; },
    set : function (val) { this._maxWinnings = val; }
});

var sgd = new SGD();
sgd.maxWinnings = 100;
alert(sgd.maxWinnings.toString());
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty